# Review posts on mobile site?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes use Stack Exchange websites on my [Nokia Lumia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia), but I am not able to find the review option on the mobile site. Is this option available for the mobile site? I am not sure if this could be put forward as a feature request.

Comment: I use the mod tools a lot on mobile. Other than markdown editing and some frustrations with inaccurate tapping which I've learned to workaround it works great.

Comment: @Flexo On your commute to work?

Comment: A lesson learned.Never post a question using your mobile because you can not see the list of similar questions

Answer (score 9):

I use mobile a lot with Stack Exchange, but I can't say I see a rationale to allow access to the review queue on the mobile site.

- The site is already minimal as it is.  It's difficult to compare revisions side-by-side on a 4 inch screen.
- The quality of reviews may suffer, as there's less flexibility to make good revisions to posts.
- It's another thing to add to the mobile site, and it already feels a fair bit cluttered (at least to me).

Not really a fan of adding reviews to the mobile site.  If you want to do reviews, either use a tablet that can see the whole site, or use a machine in which it's easier to perform reviews on.

Comment: Using a tablet is possible, however they do *not* optimize the review panel for any sort of mobile device, so it's more of an "at your own risk" thing. They do plan to eventually add review to mobile, but who knows how far away that is.

Comment: I will say that I do reviews on a tablet, and it is fully possible without a mobile version.